# Python settrace to show only root call not subsequent calls

Tags: python, trace, inspect

Is there a way to trace only the code execution of a line and ignore the remaining frames that it propagate to? For example, if I look at the functions that are called, I get things like 
_wait_for_tstate_lock, _event_pipe, send, wait, which seems like they belong to Python's internal library. I thought about doing some filtering based on the filename and class, but was wondering if there is a cleaner way to do it instead to just get the first function call or line execution. This is what my tracefunc looks like:

```py
    def tracefunc(self, frame, event, arg):
        try:
            filename = frame.f_code.co_filename
            if event == 'call' :
                fcode = frame.f_code 
                func_name = fcode.co_name
                print (func_name)

        except:
            pass
        return self.tracefunc
```